# AJAX jQuery.load versus jQuery.get

Tags: jquery, ajax

When should the load( url, data, callback ) method be used versus jQuery.get( url, data, callback, type ) when making AJAX calls with jQuery?

Comment: for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all those two functions are completely different. The 'load' function works with selectors and loads the result of AJAX call inside the selected group and the callback is to handle the "oncomplete" event of the call; while the $.get function is more general and the callback handles the success response of AJAX call where you are free to define any behavior you want. And you can find all this information just by looking at the documentation and specification of the jQuery framework.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/) you can find a good documentation.

Answer (score 17):

@Artem's answer seems to be missing the fact that the `load` is a more generic function than `get`.
According to the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#request-method), load uses `get` or `post` depending on the data. Quoting it here:

> **Request Method**
>
> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

So for the purpose of getting partial HTML content from the server & inserting it into the DOM, `load` is a better method than the `get` method, as the developer does not need to worry about handling huge data & various intermediate steps that the load function does before fetching & before inserting the content.

For instance, if you need to load partial content of a page, you could use the following expression:
`$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');`

> This retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then `jQuery` parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of `container`. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of `result`, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.

One thing to keep in mind is that, when you just need a `GET` request avoid providing an object to the data parameter & instead use the `$.param` method to get a serialized form of the request parameters.

Comment: Rather, I'd suggest using the data parameter to keep structure and data separate.  For simple queries use string concatenation (`id=' + id`) and for more complex stuff use an object and the param method (`$.param(object)` or `$.param({id: id, foo: bar})`)

Comment: @Deebster I'm assumed simpler cases. I understand that $.param is better for complex scenarios. I've edited the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

load injects the data directly into the DOM. If you don't need this behavior, use get.

Answer (score -2):

would only have to look at the jQuery code, as it is available for review. 
anyway all calls must reach the same method but respond in different ways depending on the need