# JSON message returned to HTML form

Tags: html, json, wordpress

I have an HTML form that posts values to a web service that sends back a JSON status or error message. This form is embedded in Wordpress. How might I access the returned value and display an error message?

Comment: look into jQuery's .ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Could you please post some of the code you have already? @Kelly better yet is : [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which provides more control over returned data.

Comment: .get is a shorthand form of .ajax. They are equivalent.

Comment: @Kelly Agreed - however some of the configuration is hidden from the developer -- [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would involve some Javascript, I'd highly recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with it's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function:

```
;(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form-id').bind('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: $('#form-id').attr('action'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(jsonObject) {
          if (jsonObject.error != undefined) {
            alert(jsonObject.error.message);
          }
          else {
            alert('The submission was successful');
          }
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('A connection error occurred. Please try again');
        }
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

That will make an HTTP post to the URL contained in the form's action attribute, and load the returned JSON string into a javascript object.

Comment: For debugging purposes @econner can use `console.log(jsonObject);` to display the formatted json object.

Comment: The web service returns a the success status or error message in JSON format such as the following:

Comment: {"CreateResellerResult":{"AvailableCredits":0,"DataKey":"","Id":"59fe4d79-7b1f-4560-beb4-7b2f08818da4","MayCreateRecord":false,"Name":"test1000","Products":[{"Id":"81fa46ef-57d7-4658-8eb3-92a18c7486cf","ProductCount":100,"ProductName":"product1"},{"Id":"0730e907-aba5-4095-8650-35bf4794ffc7","ProductCount":50,"ProductName":"product2"}]}}

Comment: I've updated the code above to provide an example, I've also changed it to attach the functionality to the form's submit handler.

Comment: Well it's very straight forward, try jsonObject.error.message as shown in the edit of @Clive