# store ajax data in variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

A simple ajax call, the php echos some xml text I need to appear in JPayer where myAJAXVariable is.

I need something similar to php echo which simply prints the data.

I simply want myAJAXVariable to display the data from getxml2.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {



     var myAJAXVariable = $.get("http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php", function(data){
return data; <!--here I am attempting to print the contents of getxml2.php as data-->
});



    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, myAJAXVariable, {
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3, oga",
        wmode: "window"
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX (which is what the first A stands for) you should consume the result of an AJAX call only inside the success callback, otherwise the data will not be initialized yet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php", function(data) {
        // Only here you should use the data variable as it is here and only here
        // that it is assigned

        new jPlayerPlaylist({
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        }, data, {
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "mp3, oga",
            wmode: "window"
        });
    });
});
```

or create a function:

```
var initializejPlayer = function(data) {
    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, data, {
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3, oga",
        wmode: "window"
    });
}
```

and then trigger the AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php", initializejPlayer);
});
```

Comment: @alex_borsody, inside the success callback, the `data` variable that is passed to the anonymous function will contain the result of the execution of `getxml2.php`. This being said, you should be aware of the same origin policy restriction which prevents you from sending AJAX requests to domains different than the originating domain. So if `www.freeenergymedia.com` is not the domain where you hosted your application you cannot send AJAX requests to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using the ajax method (which is much more configurable than get, read this thread [Difference between $.ajax() and $.get() and $.load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load) form additional details) to write your own `getData' function. Then you can use your function to retrieve data in your code.

I personally use this code to retrieve json data from a url, in my backbone.js app:

```
function getJSONData(myurl) 
var data;
$.ajax({
    async: false, //thats the trick
    url: myurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
       data = response;
        }
    });
return data;
}
```

you can use different datatypes (xml, json, script, or html) if you need (look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
And then, in your case, you could use it in the PlayerPlaylist object:

```
new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
}, getJSONData("http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php"), {
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3, oga",
    wmode: "window"
});
```

Hope this helps.