# What's the difference between $.get and $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between $.ajax() and $.get() and $.load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load)

What's the difference between $.get() and $.ajax

The code I've been given uses calls like this:

```
$.get(href)
   .success(function (content) {
        $('#content')
```

and:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: href + params.param,
    dataType: 'html'
})
```

Can someone explain what the difference is between these. Is there any advantage to using one over the other?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: check out this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load

Comment: Both accomplish the same work.. $.get() is basically the shorter version of the $.ajax() GET request..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain what the difference is between these.

See the documentation for [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

> Is there any advantage to using one over the other?

One is shorter. One is more flexible.

Comment: Mostly a copypasta from the API page, but this is the most objective answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

`.get()`, `.getJSON()`, `.getScript()`, `.post()`, and `.load()` are all helper methods that call `.ajax()`.

Think of them as shortcuts to get the same result with less code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that under the covers they both do the same thing. The main difference is that `.get` is a simpler interface which makes it easier to use but is a lot less flexible in terms of what you can do with it. `.ajax` on the other hand has all the functionality in there which means you can do whatever you want but is a little more complex.

As a rule of thumb use `.get` if you can and when that doesn't seem to do quite what you want move on to useing `.ajax` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about this here:

```
$.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax
$.get http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get
```

all the documentation is available on the jQuery website