# jQuery read from text file in my web folder and append to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to read values ("img1.jpg", etc.) from a text file on my server and append to a div to create a slide show.

The only catch is I need the first "slide" to have a class of **.active** applied.

Here's how my text file reads:

[image]

Here's the div I want to append to looks like:

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
   <!-- slide -->
     <div class="active item slide3 animated fadeInUpBig">
        <img src="img1.jpg" />
     </div>
   <!-- slide -->
     <div class="item slide3 animated fadeInUpBig">
        <img src="img2.jpg" />
     </div>                           
 </div>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
$(function () {
var file = "gallery.txt"; // gallery.txt PATH

$('<div />'.load(file, function(data){ // dummy DIV to hold data 
    var line      = data.split('\n');
    var NofImages = line.length -1;        
    for( i=0; i < NofImages; i++ ){
        image = './cms/data/img/gallery/homepage/'+ line[i].split('|')[2];
        $(".carousel-inner").append("<div class='active item slide3 animated fadeInUpBig'><img src='+ image +' /></div>");
    }   
}

});
```

Comment: You're missing a right parenthesis: `$('<div />').load...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    var file = "gallery.txt"; // gallery.txt PATH

    $('<div />').load(file, function(data){ // dummy DIV to hold data 
        var line      = data.split('\n'),
            NofImages = line.length -1,
            imageURL  = '';
        for( i=0; i < NofImages; i++ ){
            imageURL = './cms/data/img/gallery/homepage/'+ line[i].split('|')[2];
            $(".carousel-inner").append("<div class='item slide3 animated fadeInUpBig'><img src='"+ imageURL +"' /></div>");
        } 
        // NOW ADD THE .active TO FIRST ONE
        $('.carousel-inner').find('.item').eq(0).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[Difference between $.ajax() and $.get() and $.load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load)

Comment: `.find('.item:first')` yields one less chained function call

Comment: also, `var image` should be declared outside the for loop, other than that great answer.

Comment: @wired_in +1 for declaration

Comment: one last thing, shouldn't `NofImages` be set to `line.length` instead of `line.length - 1`

Comment: Thanks roXon! (and wired_in)

Comment: @wired_in no, there's an extra line (empty new line) in the file created by **Pulse CMS**, so lines N are always -1, that could be easily skipped inside the for loop but sould work that way too using `-1`

Comment: Nm, I see it in the question

Answer (score 1):

so add a class if you are at zero

```
var activeClass = i==0 ? "active " : "";
$(".carousel-inner").append("<div class='" + activeClass + "item...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.get("gallery.txt").done(function(response) {
    var lines = response.split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var fragments = lines[i].split("|");
        var html = "<div class='item animated fadeInUpBig slide3'><img src='" + fragments[2] + "' /></div>";
        $(".carousel-inner").append(html);
    }

    $(".carousel-inner .item").eq(0).addClass("active");
});
```