# $(slector).load('page.html #id') vs $.get and filter/find #id

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, get, load

I would like to know if there is any difference **in perfomance** (or difference at all)

Between this:

```
$(selector).load('page #myid');
```

and

```
$.get('page',function(data){
     $(selector).html( $(data).find('#myid') );
     /* depending the dom tree it should be .filter() */
})
```

Comment: @Alexander Sagen described it very well in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load

Comment: Both examples will pretty much do the same, cf. [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L133), i.e., parse the response as HTML, apply the selector and insert the result into the DOM. I guess the performance differences are negligible.

Comment: I would like to know this as well. In my experience load() is faster than "parsing" the result yourself.

Comment: But obviously it could just be my imagination

Comment: There's no appreciable difference, especially considering that most time is spent in performing the request.

Comment: @Jack: I agree. The only difference I was able to find and had a hard time putting into words was the added functionality that `get()` offers over `load()`. However, the simple example above does not indicate that they are needed so `load()` should be perfectly fine. In addition if multiple sections from a document would be required, then a single `get()` with `find()` in the callback is better than multiple individual `load()` requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say using [**load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) or [**.get()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is more to do with your intentions and requirements rather than performance.

**Load()**

---

`.load()` is for easy/simple loading of a document or a portion of it.
It will load the complete document and then using `innerHTML` parse the HTML to return only the portion you are interested in.

If you only need a fast way of loading some content into a div then `$(element).load(url, selector)` is the way to go. I would assume `load()` is optimised for just that.

**Get()**

---

Unlike `load()`, `.get()` allows setting of the `dataType` for greater flexibility such as JSONP for cross-domain requests.

It also implements the `promise` interface, giving it all the features of a `Deferred Object`.

From the docs:

> The Promise interface also allows jQuery's Ajax methods, including
>   $.get(), to chain multiple .done(), .fail(), and .always() callbacks
>   on a single request, and even to assign these callbacks after the
>   request may have completed. If the request is already complete, the
>   callback is fired immediately.

**Summary**

---

On a very basic level, there should be no worth-while performance difference between a simple `.load(url, selector)` and `.get(url, callback)`. Using either should be fine.

I would think, there is no right or wrong here as such. Use what ever suits your needs.

Ask yourself question similar to:

Do you need cross-domain (JSONP)?
Do you need to chain `.fail()`, `.done()`, etc. ?
Do you need any of the features `get()` offers which `load()` does not have?
...

If you use `load()` or `get()` depends on your requirements. Performance is secondary in this case.

Comment: But the whole document must be downloaded anyways... Lets say in a single case. With only one selector needed

Comment: What do you mean by "does not let you pass a data object"? Are you saying that `.load()` cannot perform `POST`?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: they both let you pass data. I forgot to delete those from my template before I hit post. Apologise for that.  I wanted to edit my post to highlight more of the differences between `load()` and `get()` to make it clearer that the primary focus should be on "Which method satisfies my needs" and only to look at performance secondary. For example, there is no point having a fast `load()` call if you would need to make a cross-domain call or require the use of deferreded objects etc. Hope it makes sense. There is no right or wrong as such. You use what ever suits your needs.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: the only other thing I could think of was that if you want multiple sections from a document, then a single `get()` with `find()` in the callback is better than multiple individual `load()` requests.

Comment: It was @Jack who asked about the data object

Comment: @Jack: I accidentally adressed the reponse to `ToniMichelCaubet`. That was my bad. You can POST with load off course. I had a list of differences in my template I noted and 1 by 1 going through them to verify them. I had forgotten to delete the data object references. Thank you again for noticing.

Comment: You have a template for this? ;-)

Comment: @Jack: Template might not be the right word. In the recent major edit I started by adding bullet points of `can-do/can't-do` features and then fleshed the post out while verifying the points. Not directly a template I guess :)