# Reload div in javascript loading complete page in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to reload a particular div on *ajax:success* but it is reloading the complete page in that div

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://192.168.2.210/sciAuthor1/personaldetails/cropImage",
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        parsed = $.parseJSON(response);
        var path = "http://192.168.2.210/sciAuthor1/img/upload/" + parsed;
        $('#up_img').load('http://192.168.2.210/sciAuthor1/user/profile/1'+ '#up_img');
        $edit_dialog.dialog('close');
    }
});
```

div which i want to reload

```
<div class="txtc" id="up_img">
   <?php
        $img_path = Commonfunctions::ProfileImage();
        echo $this->tag->image(array('id'=>"profile_image",$img_path,"class"=>"profile_img")) ;
   ?>
</div>
```

After running this code it reloads the complete page in #up_img.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#up_img').load(url + '#div_you_want_to_get');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply i have div <div class="txtc" id="up_img">
                <?php
                        $img_path = Commonfunctions::ProfileImage();
                        echo $this->tag->image(array('id'=>"profile_image",$img_path,"class"=>"profile_img")) ;
                ?>
            </div> and i want to reload image after uploading i tried with $('#up_img').load('http://192.168.2.210/sciAuthor1/user/profile/1'+'#up_img'); but it is loading whole page in #up_img div