# jsp div content not refreshing from js call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

jsp code:

```
<div id="myRefreshKBD">
Current Time :<%= new java.util.Date() %>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {                    
                    $('#myRefreshKBD').html('I am getting refreshed every 3 seconds..');
                }, 3000);
            });
```

My question here is whenever refreshing myRefreshKBD id from js, date should refresh...Expecting a great answer. It is sticking much now.

Comment: Looks correct. Can you post the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine.You just need to add jquery library like this.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

and you need to change your javascript like this

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function() {    
                $('#myRefreshKBD').html('Current Time : '+new Date());
            }, 3000);
        });
```

jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery".So if you want to use jQuery without downloading,use above one or you can [download](http://jquery.com/download/) it and add it in your project.

### See Also

- [Refresh Part of Page (div)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div)

Comment: thanks prince for your replay. My target to refresh the content in the div. for sample i put Current Time :<%= new java.util.Date() %>. Actually i have some session variables in the div of the jsp. From js i want to refresh it and display with new values

Comment: updated my answer.I think this is what you are looking for.see the link.I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks prince it is useful. I tired this way. But no luck on this. 
<div id="myRefreshKBD"> <c:forEach var="moduleVO" items="${sessionScope.MODULE_NS.pageDetails.moduleList}" varStatus="status"> </div>

here the sessionScope.MODULE_NS.pageDetails.moduleList variable is not updating once ajax call happen. am not passing response from ajax. In ajax am updating MODULE_NS.pageDetails.moduleList value. Based upon ajax response flag am refresh the exisiting div. load function also not helpful to load jsp inside WEB-INF folder.