# Load div in a page without refresh whole of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I was make a experiment with DnD html5 and I need to make function who can bring back my div into formerly without refreshing a page.

This is my html,

```
<div class='panel panel-default' >
 <div class="canvas-wrap">
  <div id="canvastowr">
   <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/tower_bg/sst3/tower2.png" draggable="false" width="450" height="460">
  </div>
  <div class="overcanvas" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div class="mw-rf">
   //this img move into dive class overcanvas and I need to make them back
   <img id="mwdragable" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/mw.png" class="overmw" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" width="40" height="40" >
   <img id="rfdragable" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/rf.png" class="overrf" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" width="40" height="40" >
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I was try [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) jquery, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div) question. But didn't work for me.
this is my button to refresh the div back into former, but not work.

```
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
 $('#canvas-wrap').load(document.URL +  ' #canvas-wrap');
}, false);
```

`document.URL` not work for me. then I must use what?
please help me.

**EDIT:**

this is the screen shot: before I dropping the image, that is a fullscreen modal I need to drop the image to div rectangle whose overlaying the image tower. [image: before dropping]

After I dropped the image :[image]

I need to make that clear button. bring back the draggable image comeback into first position.

Comment: You want to load the current page, into a div on the current page? Is that correct? Or just a section of it after `#`? If the latter, remove the space before the `#`

Comment: I don't see any tags using this `clear` id.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div) question, I must include a space before the hastag.

Comment: @Bravo ya my button at the top of div panel. Believe me I was try the `clear` button with `alert();` and no problem with that

Comment: On page load, get the position of the circle element using javascript (or css). Clicking the reset button can then return the element to that position. I wouldn't mess around reloading for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
 $('#canvas-wrap').load(window.location.href +  ' #canvas-wrap');
}, false);
```

Use `window.location.href` for current URL

But this will only replace it with what's already there so what's the point?

Comment: the url `window.location.href` actually give same url. not work. whether it affects the modal that I use ?

Comment: @jboxxpradhana, you mean you want to load from a different html file?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I need to bring back the image to go out of `div class="overcanvas"></div>` after I'm dropping them into that div

Comment: @DarrenSweeney No, I need to load the `<div class="canvas-wrap">` again back to normal, like before I do dragging the image

Comment: @DarrenSweeney are you understand with my question? or I must edit my question to including screen shot?

Comment: Any more information you could provide would help, yes

Comment: This could be easy if only you made it clear early, now It's dinner time which people already away from computer, I'm using android now, I'll upvote this answer