# Reload PHP script on page every 5 seconds (file_get_contents())

Tags: php, web

So i have a web page that displays logs of users using my software in 'real-time', but the only way the log list will refresh is if i reload the entire page. I was wondering if it was possible to execute a simple php script like this every 5 seconds without needing to refresh the page:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents(myurl); ?>
```

i know i could host this script on another page and put it in an iframe and refresh that every 5 seconds, but i was wondering if i could just refresh only the php code?

Comment: i dont think that's the right dupe, i think he wants ajax to reload part of the page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div)

Comment: LOL, this got marked as a dupe? StackOverFlow needs to regulate it's crazy staff / moderators...

Comment: we are not staff. mistakes can be made, i can change the dupe to the one i posted but was waiting to here back from you.

Comment: @Dagon you're welcome to reopen and mark yours as the one you think. I posted that dupe for 2 reasons. 1) That's what I thought the question was about. 2) There was an answer given for same.

Comment: @JeffCoderr I agree with Dagon; we are not perfect. You could have also posted a comment under the answer that was given, yet I saw nothing of the sorts. You just went and called "me" crazy (which in a way I probably am *lol* in my own right). I made a mistake and that's that and I apologize for it. It was an "honest" mistake.

Comment: @Dagon No need for you to reopen, I just did now.

Comment: Ajaxs would be a good place to start.

Answer (score -4):

If you've got access to the shell or to the crontab you could create a cronjob with this script that runs every 5 seconds.