# How to refresh only metabox in wordpress product page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In my wordpress admin panel Inside product page there is a metabox called product categories.For adding new category there is a option also, after adding new category its not getting updated automatically,If i refresh the whole page then list get update. 
[image: Screen shot of category list and add new option.]

I need to update the category list without refreshing whole page when i click Add New Product Category button. 
Can any one help me out for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am able to solve this problem, i referred this link for solution 
[stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div)