# reload specific element using vanilla JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, html

how do I refresh a specific element in html using only vanilla javascript.

the goal is after adding an attribute to it with a value.

I will refresh the element.

Comment: Please post your code. Show us what are you trying to do. What is the desired result.

Comment: you can use ajax call to get the content and update the specific element with a div ...this link could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div

Comment: thanks for the reply guys! :)
but I don't want to use jQuery as I have said vanilla JavaScript only

Answer (score 1):

Libraries like **React** are built for this purpose. But we can sort of do it with pure Javascript too. Here's what we need to do:

- delete the element with `parent.removeChild(element)`
- create another one with `document.createElement(element)`
- set the properties the way you want `element.setAttribute(name, value)`
- add it to the parent element with `parent.appendChild(newElement)`

I have working example here in this link: https://codepen.io/edo9k/pen/poyRJJN?editors=1010

But you can also update the element directly, instead of 'refreshing' it. Which can be done with `element.setAttribute` or getting the attribute directly like a I do changing the font size of the element in line 20 of the example: `elm.style.fontSize = counter + "pt";`.

Your question lacks context, but depending on what you're trying to do, you should consider a library or some alternative method of updating this element. There might be security issues doing it like the way I'm proposing here, both by modifying attributes directly or by deleting/adding a new element.

You can find detailed explanation of all these API function in Mozilla's Web Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API