# Use of location.reload() to refresh the current page when this page is loaded within another page

Tags: jquery, html, load, reload, window.location

I want the page to be refreshed after the user has clicked a certain button but the problem is this page A is loaded within another page B so when I use location.reload(), it always refreshes back to B than A.

For instance,

My page B is called customerMain.html, and inside I use jQuery to load the page A (called customerOrders.html) when the customer clicks "Orders" tab.

Page B:

```
<button id="orders-page">Orders</button>
<div id="page-switch"></div>
<script>
  $("#orders-page").on("click", function(){
    $("page-switch").load("customerOrders.html");
  });
<script>
```

Page A:

```
<button id="refresh-page">Refresh</button>
<script>
  location.reload() // Refreshes to Page B BUT want Page A
<script>
```

I tried to solve it by changing location.reload() to window.location.href = "customerOrders.html", but the problem on this is actually in my project, Page B have other tabs too but this command will eliminate the tabs in Page B and only show Page A's content, and the CSS I predefined in Page B but also applied to page A(I know it's better to link the external CSS) also get lost.

Any good idea to solve this? Thanks!

PS: Yea, I mean after click Refresh button in Page A it should perform the same thing as you click the Orders button in Page B

Answer (score 0):

I got a hint from [Refresh Part of Page (div)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div), and change my line of code to

```
$("page-switch").load("customerOrders.html");
```

and it works! I didn't know we can use jQuery to select an element from the outside page if this page is contained by that page.

You are more than welcome to post another better answer here.

**But then I have a new question,** what about I have a div in page B that has the same id within a div in Page A (A contains B)? If I select this div in page B will it actually override it in Page A and select the div in page B?

Comment: I tested it, and it actually selected the one in Page B than Page A, so it overrides. Then jQuery always selects the one in the same page first before checking if there is one in another linked/contained page! Correct me if I'm wrong :)