# Should reload of html element should be in JSP when new data from server is requested

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using JSP to render the HTML content. Once jsp is loaded on page, I want to reload a part of JSP to fill new content (content is already present) on button click. Is this right approach to take? Or this part should done in JS script?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use AJAX. Do you have a specific problem or something you have attempted?

Comment: Using jazva script is one correct way to go. Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div

Comment: @JamesJackson data get loaded in one go. I show only part of content coming from server. On button click i show the rest of content present. So not making an extra ajax call to fetch the data

Comment: But you can use an ajax and only use a portion of the response.

Comment: @JulienRevaultd'A... Thanks. For conformation a lot of data is there. It will okay to send data for jsp to js on button click then?

Comment: @JamesJackson any ref. where i can read up on this. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this example : https://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/WQXXT/

Comment: If using jQuery you can use `$(response).filter('#someId');`

Comment: cool thanks @JulienRevaultd'A... ,@JamesJackson