# How to reload specific <div> when we press suffle button without reloading whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a simple dice game with HTML, CSS, and JS.

So whenever I reload the page the dice will change OR press the shuffle button the dice will change i.e; it refreshes the whole page but I want to refresh only one div("context div") Because I added animated background So whenever the page reloads the background also starting from the beginning so I don't want to reload the whole page, So please can anyone help me

This is my code

```js
var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

var randomDiceImage = "dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png";

var randomImageSource = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JallaJaswanth/Dice-Game/main/images/" + randomDiceImage;

var image1 = document.querySelectorAll("img")[0];

image1.setAttribute("src", randomImageSource);


var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

var randomImageSource2 = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JallaJaswanth/Dice-Game/main/images/dice" + randomNumber2 + ".png";

document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src", randomImageSource2);

if (randomNumber1 > randomNumber2) {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins!";
} else if (randomNumber2 > randomNumber1) {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins!";
} else {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Draw!";
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.dice {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background-color: #393E46;
}

h1 {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-shadow: 5px 0 #232931;
  font-size: 8rem;
  color: #4ECCA3;
}

p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #4ECCA3;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

.button {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  background-color: #38D2D2;
  background-image: radial-gradient(93% 87% at 87% 89%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0%, transparent 86.18%), radial-gradient(66% 66% at 26% 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 69.79%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), inset 0px 3px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset 0px -8px 36px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0px 1px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 2px 19px 31px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,700');
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
}

.context {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vh;
}

.context-2 {
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bolder;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60vh;
}

.context h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.area {
  background: #4e54c8;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.circles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
  bottom: -150px;
}

.circles li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 25%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 10%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 70%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 65%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 75%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 35%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 20%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 85%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 11s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Let's Play Dice</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="area">
    <ul class="circles">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="context">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Refresh Me</h1>

      <div class="dice">
        <p>Player 1</p>
        <img class="img1" src="images/dice6.png">
      </div>

      <div class="dice">
        <p>Player 2</p>
        <img class="img2" src="images/dice6.png">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <main>
        <button class="button" onClick="window.location.reload();"><span>Suffle</span></button>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

so please suggest to me how to reload only specific div(Only dice should change) rather than the whole page
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: have ever you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886578/refresh-part-of-page-div

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

To reload a section of the page, you could use **jquerys** load In your case it could be like this:

```
function updateDiv()
{ 
    $( "#divId" ).load(window.location.href + " #divId" );
}
```

**Note:** divId is the id of the div you want to reload

Don't disregard the space within the load element selector: + " #here"
This function can be called within an interval, or attached to a click event

Comment: I added this code in js file but It Didn't working, Can you please explain clearly, I'm very new to this language, So can you tell me where exactly I should add this, And How exactly I need is When ever I press shuffle button Only Cubes should change (Actualy if page reloads then it will change to new faces), I hope you understood What I'm telling. Thanks for your replay