# .load doesn't refresh my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created ajax to get start time and end time from another page and setInterval for this function every second like this.

```js
setInterval(function () {
    CheckTime()
}, 1000);

function CheckTime() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Get_TIme.php",
        success: function (result) {
            var time = result.split('|');
            var start_time = time[0];
            var end_time = time[1];

            var getTime = new Date();
            var currentHours = getTime.getHours();
            var currentMinutes = getTime.getMinutes();
            var currentTime = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes;

            if ((currentTime == start_time) || (currentTime == end_time)) {
                $('#first').load('demo.php #first'); //reload div
            }
        }
    });
```

At first time when `current time = start time`, `<div>` can refresh itself. But when `current time = end time`, `<div>` doesn't reload itself. I don't what happen on this code. But I replace alert before  `if((currentTime==start_time)||(currentTime==end_time))` like this:

```
alert("something");
if((currentTime==start_time)||(currentTime==end_time))
{
   $('#first').load('demo.php #first'); //reload div
}
```

`<div>` can reload itself when `current time = end time`. Anyone can suggest me what happen on my code.

Comment: I don't think .load() will work in an ajax() cause it is like an ajax call. load() might works if u use it oustide the ajax function? read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load

Answer (score 1):

I think load must be use like that :

```
$('#first').load('demo.php');
```

this is what I saw in the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
if((currentTime==start_time)||(currentTime==end_time))
{
   $('#first').load('demo.php'); //reload div
}
```

**if you want show #first use following;**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         $("#first").css("class","active");
}
```