# Ajax and jQuery request to serverside

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax and jQuery to send the data submitted in a form to the server and retrieve the response form the server and serve it up on the webpage again. What method should I be using do accomplish this?

I am not sure if I should use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` or if I should be using any other of the methods on the jQuery API.
Could someone please shed some light on this question?
Thanks.

Comment: use $.ajax() as it is a more pwerfull wrapper and get is only a shorthand for $.ajax() GET request

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX submit form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Answer (score 1):

A nice and simple tutorial for you
[***Call ASP.Net Page Method using jQuery AJAX Example***](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)

See also
 [***Difference between $.ajax() and $.get() and $.load()***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load)

Answer (score 0):

hope that can help you:

jquery and ajax request:

```
$("#submitButton").on("click", function () {
  $("#formid").submit(submitForm());
  return false;
});
var submitForm = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $("#formid").serialize(),
        url: '@Url.Action("function","controller")',
        success: function (data) {
             alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Function(SubmitViewModel viewModel)
    return Json("response from the server is here", "application/json", Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```