# Where to use $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am learning to implement Ajax using Jquery in ASP.NET MVC5 and have found following important functions:-

a. `$.get`

b. `$.post`

c. `$(selector).load`

d. `$.ajax`

As per my learning so far I am able to understand the scenarios where we should be using `$.get`, `$.post and $(selector).load`, but I am not able to understand where i should use `$.ajax`

Can any one please explain where I should use `$.ajax`? As I am not able understand the scenario where I should use `$.ajax`?

Regards

Mandeep

Comment: Pretty sure $.ajax is just the generic ajax function for jquery, whereas $.post and $.get imply their respective ajax types

Comment: `$.get()` is just a shorthand method ([refer documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)) - ditto for `$.post()` and `.load()` (and there are more such as `$.getJSON()`)

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get(...) = $.ajax({method: "GET",...});
$.post(...) = $.ajax({method: "POST",...});
```

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax() Performs an async AJAX request is the most configurable one, where you get fine grained control over HTTP headers and such.

More you see the @Alexander Sagen answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870130/5566169