# Django not responding to ajax autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I searched for term "bi" which should return a username with initial "bi..."
but nothing is displayed, No dropdown Here are my codes.

**search.html**

```
<html>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="search4">search4: </label>
  <input id="search4">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#search4").autocomplete({
    source: '/rating/searchresult/',
    minLength: 2,
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

**url.py**

```
url(r'^searchresult/', 'rating.views.search_images'),
```

**views.py**

```
def search_images(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        s = request.GET.get("term", '')
        search_result = UploadImage.objects.filter(user__username__icontains = s )[:20]
        search = []
        for result in search_result:
            json_d = {}
            json_d['id'] = result.id
            json_d['name'] = result
            json_d['value'] = result
            search.append(json_d)
        data = m_json.dumps(search)
    else:
        data = 'error'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

if I search a value Ajax doesnot respond and returned nothing in dropdown, while the term is passed in URl

```
[04/Aug/2016 08:48:46] "GET /rating/searchresult/?term=bi HTTP/1.1" 200 2661
```

I can't understand where is the problem Ajax or Django
[Also my content type is text html see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40yYP.png)

Comment: Try to debug it. You can try using `print` and `alert` statements for quick check of where the data is missing.

Comment: I tried `print data` and `print s`, Nothing in view is displayed

Comment: Then must be problem in Django if it's not printing data what will come to Ajax Resopnse obviously nuthing.

Comment: Where exactly is your ajax part? I don't see one. Is this the only code or have shown us only a part of it? If its a part of the code, then kindly show the complete javascript

Comment: `autocomplete()` is the whole ajax here, i refered [http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/]

Comment: The link you just posted says "Page doesn't exists". Anyway, check out my answer. It will give you some idea about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so technically you are doing it all wrong.

The `source` attribute of `autocomplete` requires an array of strings or data that you want to provide the user as autocomplete options in an input field.

Now what you are trying to do is to simply give the `url` corresponding to a particular view class or method in your `views.py` in your `source` of `autocomplete`, when actually what you need to do was to get an `ajax` response by hitting that `url` and then you'll get the required response from that class/method corresponding to that url.

Now you'll feed this `response` to the source of `autocomplete`

See here how the `source` of `autocomplete` works -> http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

And the official documentation of `ajax` -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Documentation of `$.get()` -> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

So your javascript file will look like this:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
      populateSearchFieldList();
      // all other code according to your needs

});   

function populateSearchFieldList() {

    var url = "/rating/searchresult/";
    $.get(url, function(response) {

            // console.log("Success..!!");
            console.log(response);

           // now in views.py, you've returned a list in which every 
           // object has an id, name and value but you
           // want only the names in your autocomplete. So for that, first
           // you'll have to create a list of just the names and then feed
           // that list to the source of autocomplete. Like this

           var searchFieldOptions = [];
           var i = 0;

           $.each(response,function(){
                searchFieldOptions.push(response[i].name);
                i++;
           });

           // and now make the source of autocomplete as 
           // searchFieldOptions like this

           $(function(){
                $("#search4").autocomplete({
                    source: searchFieldOptions,
                    minLength: 2,
                });
            });               

       });
}
```

Now if it worked successfully, then you'll have the required data in the `response` you received in the `success` function. Now you can use this `response` as the `source` of `autocomplete` if its simply a list or can further modify this `response` and form an `array` of desired contents as per your requirements.

Comment: thnks for replying, but where to put the autocomplete function. in your code, sorry i dont know JS, i juz followed the given blog

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show you where you can put the `autocomplete` function.

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand what to pass in data, I tried your script, but it doesnt work

Comment: nothing is shown on console, also the term is not passed, but my friend did the same thing from  the blog and it worked

Comment: I also got an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: Okay so basically, there are two ways to get the info from your `views.py` which you need to display in an `input` field of a form. Either you use Ajax call (when you are submitting some form data, and in response to that your `views` return some data, which you use in your autocomplete) or you can simple make a `GET` call as well when you don't have any to data to submit but all you want is to get the data from your views which will be used in your autocomplete.
So do you have any data to submit and then get the response accordingly or you simply need some data from views, nothing to submit?

Comment: I just want to get the username from model, when i type b.. which should show username with initial b

Comment: In that case, you don't really need an `ajax` call. I `get` call will be more suitable. Let me edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: but how can it return the username as i m typing, doesnt it require ajax

Comment: Yea `ajax` is required. $.get() is just a shorthand for $.ajax() but abstracts some of the configurations away. I'll edit my answer, and that will make things a lot clear for you. :)

Comment: See this for a better understanding -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870086/difference-between-ajax-and-get-and-load

Comment: sorry for late reply, i tried ur code, now the term is not even passed into the URL

Comment: Where exactly is that `term` in your HTML?? I mean what data do you want to send from your frontend i.e., html to backend, which you are calling as `term`? Coz I see you are trying to access something known as `term` in your views in `GET`, but where is this `term` in your html?? It has to be somewhere in your html?