# $.ajaxSetup not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, request-headers

I have the following function that set up the headers of my `AJAX` requests:

```
self.authenticate = function () {
    self.token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
    var headers = {};

    if (self.token) {
        headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + self.token;
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: headers
        });
    }
}
```

But this is not working, when I check the headers in the developers toll (F12) or in Fiddler, I don't see the custon header there, but when I set the header on the request and not through `ajaxSetup` it works perfectly.

The `authenticate` functions is being called in the Layout page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var avm = new AuthenticationViewModel();
     avm.authenticate();
});
```

And `self.token` is not `null`.

For example, for this request:

```
self.getUsers = function (callback) {
    $.get("../API/Users/GetUsers/",callback);
}
```

these are the headers: 
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question.  Are you actually calling the authenticate function anywhere?

Comment: @Archer Please see my edited question.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `avm.authenticate();` and your `$.get("../API/Users/GetUsers/");` and make sure that: 1. Authentication is actually called. 2. Authentication is called **before** get requests.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I did so, the answer for both is- yes.

Comment: Before `if (self.token) {` , type `console.log(self.token)` and let me know what you are getting

Comment: @SagarV : `LSHBs5movtDDo5fR5kzpQDCr8C88stGN-XMH-gL0UZobAL-WmutQ0F5KX0Y-f6TcXUeCgRmXCuhDMuX26_c3LpOcUIZVigzGMNHc4OyaIe82ALdgNJZaeyYToto5aMSvDpcAIqyjvcnm9y-wJQWFl9pNcprf2TAf2etBIHrI6mPQ4RraiQgNWPnv2dxuDTd0B54V8wUD_NN0Bkw9cCyfPFZteef2cm9XdW2OiJHfR5hCF6zr2DxBsjA4aplRgCrBx5AmuYvIn5KrFV36G4RmOcPH5d6fQH920CIDuATCQJKzpSxwPlHEVGVhSjRWzUeSgm7wdcYWj18F9H0NpyyFxb51VIKKZ0d4f-rtugCgqHeJMOpIrVnmCqo73t15o6Tc-F-7U-B49w5VdYjN2CmneW9w8risBObEATvjkND486Vx2Vnwc5hXn_4rNsoQo-nPi4wXtA_vSUr8iPWt2tDtm5V5s0dU71VW9x4ThB7zd_efd6dQA3Y3VqunnozOoaT10ps9`

Comment: Please check the value of `headers`. Is it really an object containing `Authorization` ?

Comment: @SagarV `Object {Authorization: "Bearer LSHBs5movtDDo5fR5kzpQDCr8C88stGN-XMH-gL0UZo…tm5V5s0dU71VW9x4ThB7zd_efd6dQA3Y3VqunnozOoaT10ps9"}`

Comment: are you calling it in document.ready ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146645/discussion-between-sagar-v-and-user3378165).

Comment: Have you confirmed if you reach the inside of the `if` statement by putting a console.log in there? Also, what happens if you copy/paste this `$.ajaxSetup()` code just before your first instance of calling `$.ajax()`? Does it work then?

Comment: What is `AuthenticationViewModel`?

Comment: @therobinkim The answer for both questions is Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up moving:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var avm = new AuthenticationViewModel();
     avm.authenticate();
});
```

From the `Layout` page to the page itself and that solved the issue.

AuthenticationViewModel-Creates a new AuthenticationViewModel for logging users in and getting their info.

Answer (score 7):

[$.ajaxSetup](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) sets default values for future Ajax requests.

> Its use is not recommended as suggested in the JQuery documentation.

Anyways, as it sets the default values for future calls it must execute before all ajax calls that depends on those default values. For example, if you didn't mention the `url` of the call, the default `url` that configured in the `$ajaxSetup` will be the `url` of the call. If the call you made depends on those defaults then this code

```
self.authenticate = function () {
    self.token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
    var headers = {};
    if (self.token) {
        headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + self.token;
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: headers
        });
    }
}
```

must execute before the below call is made.

```
self.getUsers = function () {
    $.get("../API/Users/GetUsers/");
}
```

Now check this

***************[Plunker for answer](https://plnkr.co/edit/av4v5Tl8FzSc0krqOdjx?p=preview)****************

In that plunker go to **network** tab in the **developer console** by pressing **F12** and check the headers in those calls made by `$.ajax()` and `$.get()`

In the plunker I observed that(**Points to be read**),

- If the call is **`$.ajax()`** then the headers are showing and the `url` of the call is the `url` that is mentioned in the `$.ajaxSetup`
- If the call is **`$.get()`** then the headers are not showing and the `url` of the call is the `plunker` url means in your case it will be **`http://MySite/`** etc.

> **`$.ajax()`** is the most configurable one, where you get fine grained
>   control over HTTP headers and such. You're also able to get direct
>   access to the XHR-object using this method. Slightly more fine-grained
>   error-handling is also provided. Can therefore be more complicated and
>   often unecessary, but sometimes very useful. You have to deal with the
>   returned data yourself with a callback.
>
> **`$.get()`** is just a shorthand for **`$.ajax()`** but abstracts some of the
>   configurations away, setting reasonable default values for what it
>   hides from you. Returns the data to a callback. It only allows
>   GET-requests so is accompanied by the **`$.post()`** function for similar
>   abstraction, only for POST

For more info

[DIFFERENCE BETWEEN $.ajax() and $.get(), $.post()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870130/6554634)

Just test the plunker if you want.

---

**Image of $.ajax() call**

[image]

---

**Image of $.get() call**

[image]

**Hence, If you want to set the `headers` just use `$.ajax()` instead of `$.get()`**

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer, I tried changing `$.get()` to `$.ajax()` but still the same issue...

Comment: @user3378165 add a plunker with your issue. I will resolve it or check the plunker i added that has working fine

Comment: I checked your plunker and it seems correct, but the thing for me doesn't work...

Comment: Can you make a demo plunker of your problem?

Answer (score -1):

the syntax should be like

```
headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
```

ie; you may rewrite your functions as

```
self.authenticate = function () {
    self.token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);

    if (self.token) {
       //headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + self.token;
       $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {Authorization:  'Bearer ' + self.token}
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it is the same thing but I tried that, didn't help:(