# Ajaxify links with a particular class using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Is it possible to load all the links with class 'ajax' without refreshing the page? The complete body content should be changed, the page title and the url should so it can be bookmarked.

Comment: Have a look at pjax http://pjax.heroku.com/

Comment: @Dogbert that script is massive for what effectively should a few lines of jQuery. edit- The example on the sites homepage doesn't even work.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz, it does but you have to tick the checkbox. Agreed though, too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a.blah').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    $.get('page.html', function(data){
        $('body').html(data);
    });
});
```

That is probably the simplest way, replace blah with your class, and page.html with your page.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for all links with a certain class, 'target' is the id of your main content div. It requires no editing of your current mark up.

```
$('.class').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#target').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: For the difference between my response and Dunhamzzz, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246137/ajax-jquery-load-versus-jquery-get

Comment: @rickyduck .load is fine for OPs needs?

Comment: thought it relevent to highlight the difference for future ref, knowledge is key! $.load is fine though, I'd use $.load in this instance

Comment: But can i change the page title and url with this?

Comment: Yeah, depends how you want to do it, it will require some jQuery knowledge. Personally, I'd put the page title in the `<a title=""` attribute, or you could be more advanced and fetch it from the ajax reponse.