# jQuery.get() doesn't work for me.. but .load does

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, load

I am trying to use jQuery.get(), since .load only loads the html snippet, but the jquery css isn't applied on this content.

```
$("#content").load("home.html", function() {
            });


$.get('home.html', function(data) {
            $('.content').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');
            });
```

When I type '#content' it loads an empty page.
What means this data? Do I have to name something data to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it .content or #content?

Comment: ^^^ what he said, you're mixing up selectors, otherwise they are exactly the same.

Comment: "When I type '#content' it loads an empty page."

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('home.html', function(data) {
            $('.content').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');
            });
```

You seem to be referring to the target in two different ways. #content vs .content.

Possibly it should be

```
$.get('home.html', function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');
            });
```

Comment: "When I type '#content' it loads an empty page."

Comment: I would inspect "data" in a JS debugger to check its content

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your selector in the get callback handler.

```
$.get('home.html', function(data) {
    $('#content').html(data);//Note #content, you are using .content
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: That's genius, why didn't anyone think of that ?

Comment: "When I type '#content' it loads an empty page."

Answer (score -1):

load() and get() are very different functions, check out: [AJAX jQuery.load versus jQuery.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246137/ajax-jquery-load-versus-jquery-get)

Check the path of "home.html" and take a look at the result (data) you get. I guess, your data in "home.html" is not what you or $.get() is expecting.

As already mentioned: maybe you confused ".content" and "#content"!

```
$.get('home.html', function(data) {
    alert("Result: " + data);
});
```

Comment: load() is just a shortcut for $.get() that also inserts the content, so they aren't that different ?

Comment: @adeneo: as you already mentioned: they are different. Maybe not that different in your opinion, but they are! :)