# Unexpected Identifier Within jQuery.ajax() At Context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to send back a string var from `ProParty.php` and load it into the tag ID `"PartyTitle"`. However I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

On this line: `context: document.getElementById("PartyTitle").innerHTML`

Here is the ajax that loads with the body of the document:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "ProParty.php",
      data: { Action: "Load", loadWhat : "PartyName" , PartyId: "1" },
      type: "GET",
      context: document.getElementById("PartyTitle").innerHTML
    }).done(function() {

    });
```

Here is the HTML tag that I want to edit/fill.

```
<h2><p id= "PartyTitle"> Editing Your Party  </h2>
```

Comment: missing the comma after "GET"

Comment: Check here http://jshint.com

Comment: BTW, what are you expecting passing a string as context to do?

Comment: @KennyThompson okay got that

Comment: @A.Wolff Well I just looked at some things... and yes what I have there is junk. I want to load the result from the php file it to that tag. How would I write it correctly?

Comment: `context` should be a ***plain object***, not a string. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Sounds like you would have better to use load() instead: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I have edited my answer below @A.Wolff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma after "GET" on the previous line.
The following should work:

```
$.ajax({
  url     : "ProParty.php",
  data    : { Action: "Load", loadWhat : "PartyName" , PartyId: "1" },
  type    : "GET",
  context : document.getElementById("PartyTitle").innerHTML
}).done(function() {

});
```

*Edit to answer your question in the above comments

```
$.ajax({
  url     : "ProParty.php",
  data    : { Action: "Load", loadWhat : "PartyName" , PartyId: "1" },
  type    : "GET",
  success : function (data) {
    $('#PartyTitle').html(data);
  }
});
```

-- with load ( http://api.jquery.com/load/ ) --

```
$('#PartyTitle').load('ProParty.php', { Action: "Load", loadWhat: "PartyName", PartyId: "1" });
```

Comment: +1 I understand question like that too, even you could use `load()` instead, which exists for this exact purpose. That's said, passing data as object to load() make it request of type POST

Comment: You would be using less code.  It sounds like it calls ajax in the background anyways.  See: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-load-vs-jquery-ajax and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246137/ajax-jquery-load-versus-jquery-get

Comment: Ya, `load()` is a shorthand for some ajax request, setting content on matched element

Comment: @KennyThompson I just started playing with ajax yesterday so I'm really limping along. I know its a lot but could you rewrite this to use load() so that I can see how it transfers over?

Comment: Thank you Very much! Is there some way that I can give you some extra points or something?

Comment: @A.Wolff  lol... sorry.. I thought you were the OP this whole time.. my bad.

Comment: @WhiteShadow I don't think so. =]  Thanks for the upvote/answer selection.  that's enough

Comment: @KennyThompson None of my variables seem to be passing through. Is this the propper with to access them in php? `$loadWhat = $_GET['loadwhat'];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55931/discussion-between-kenny-thompson-and-whiteshadow).

Answer (score 1):

According to the API documentation, `context` should be a *plain object* **not** a *string*.

Change your code like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ProParty.php",
  data: { Action: "Load", loadWhat : "PartyName" , PartyId: "1" },
  type: "GET",
  context: document.getElementById("PartyTitle")
}).done(function() {
    // Reference the element as $(this)...
});
```

Reference: [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)