# How can I go to a div that is at the end of the view when the view loads?

Tags: jquery, html

My question is this:

I have a main view and inside it I have a div where another view is loaded with jquery.
When I load the div with jquery, the result is correct, but it puts me back at the top of the view and my div is down
How can I make the div content load without moving the current scroll position?

html:

```
<html><body>
...
<div class="col-md-12" id="productList"></div>
...
</body></html>
```

jquery:

```
function loadProduct(){
    var op_sort = document.getElementById('op_sort').value;
    var op_dir = document.getElementById('op_dir').value;
    $.get("showProductsListSorted",
        {op_sort: op_sort, op_dir: op_dir},
        function(response){
            $('#productList').html(response);
        }
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with jsp. that is html that you keep referring to as jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Longestwayround for his answer, it is an option that I will use in other tasks.
But what I was really looking for was I wrestled a bear once's suggestion, with which using javascript and an Id, directly places the view in position.

JavaScript:

```
$( "#productList" ).load("url",
    {op_sort: op_sort, op_dir: op_dir, op_page: op_page, id_pro: id_pro, id_cat: id_cat},
    function() {
        $('#focusAfterSort').focus();
    }
);
```

Html:

```
    <div class="col-md-12" id="focusAfterSort" tabindex="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

after you load the content, make the change:

```
...
$('#productList').html(response);
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#productList').offset().top }, 'fast');
```

That will scroll the window to your element, but the location of the scrollbar probably will not be exactly where it was prior to loading.

UPDATE

even better, try using the load function:

```
$( "#productList" ).load( "showProductsListSorted",
        {op_sort: op_sort, op_dir: op_dir}, function() {
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#productList').offset().top }, 'fast');
});
```

SO has a nice discussion on $.get() vs $.load() here: [AJAX jQuery.load versus jQuery.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246137/ajax-jquery-load-versus-jquery-get)

UPDATE 2

To keep the scrollbar exactly where it was, use:

```
var initialScrollTop=$('html, body').scrollTop();
$( "#productList" ).load( "showProductsListSorted",
        {op_sort: op_sort, op_dir: op_dir}, function() {
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: initialScrollTop }, 'fast');
});
```

Comment: this does not move focus it just scrolls the window. to set focus add: `$('#productList').focus()`

Comment: thanks. fixed it. I hope I didn't misunderstand your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Longestwayround. This is a solution but I prefer not to see the scroll even if it is done fast. Is there any way to keep view at that point?