# JQuery get method seems to be not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been looking for a way to get the same navigation bar on every page.  Right now, I have a jQuery script that is loaded onto every page, that should replace a div placeholder; however, when I run the program, the navigation bar is simply not there.

JQuery code:

```
$(function() {
$("#dropdown").hover(function() {
    $("#submenu").stop();
    $("#submenu").slideToggle(500);
});

$("#submenu").hover(function()
{
    $("#submenu").stop();
    $("#submenu").slideToggle(500);
});

$.get("navigation.html", function(data){
    $("#nav-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
});
});
```

Navigation file:

```
<nav>
<a href = "index.html">CV Game Development</a>
<div class="menu">
    <div id="dropdown">Tutorials</div>
        <div id="submenu">
            <a href="beginner.html">Beginner</a>
            <a href="intermediate.html">Intermediate</a>
            <a href="advanced.html">Advanced</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Actual HTML file to be used:

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>CV Game Development</title>
    <div id = "nav-placeholder"></div>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id = "intro">Welcome</h1>
    <h3 id = "subintro">to the CV Game Development website</h3>

    <p id = "info">Here is an abundance of information to get you started making 2D games with GameMaker: Studio.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like it should work, and yet, it doesn't.  Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What's in your JS console? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: Why your `<div id = "nav-placeholder"></div>` inside `<head>`

Comment: You should be using `.load()` instead of making an asynchronous request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246137/ajax-jquery-load-versus-jquery-get. p/s: On a side note, using jQuery is a really ugly solution for your problem: use a templating system instead (you don't even need a CMS to do that). Jekyll is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

**1st**: give `<nav>` an id to be

```
<nav id="nav">
```

**2nd**: you can use `.load()` instead of `.get()` .. And the`.load()` code should looks like

```
$('#nav-placeholder').load("navigation.html #nav");
```

> The above code will wrap `<nav id="nav">` into `<div id="nav-placeholder">`

**3rd**: if you need to replace with you can use `unwrap()` instead .. so your code should be like this

```
$('#nav-placeholder').load("navigation.html #nav" , function(){
   $('#nav').unwrap();
});
```

**4th**: I don't know yet *Why your `<div id = "nav-placeholder"></div>` inside `<head>`* but any way I tested it and the code will work even if its wrapped to `<head>` ..

Answer (score 1):

As *Mohamed-Yousef* noticed in comments you have placed your **nav-placeholder div** element in **head** tag, which is wrong place for it. 
It should be inside **body** element.

Also your **meta,** **css** and **script** tags must be in **head** element.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>CV Game Development</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
  <h1 id="intro">Welcome</h1>
  <h3 id="subintro">to the CV Game Development website</h3>

  <p id="info">Here is an abundance of information to get you started making 2D games with GameMaker: Studio.</p>
</body>

</html>
```