# I am facing error when Including html file in another html file using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using this code, When I run this code in browser I am getting a blank page, Help me out please, Thanks in advance.

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      jQuery.noConflict();
      $("#includedContent").load("a.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

my **a.html** is following

```
<html>
    <p>this is included file</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any error log on the console or network logs

Comment: try replacing `<div id="includedContent"></div>` with `<iframe src="a.html"></iframe>`, if still there is blank page, then you have issues with url

Comment: yes It works, @Arvind

Comment: @JamieSouthwell, are you browsing file with `file:///` protocol?

Comment: Yes I am @Arvind

Answer (score 2):

you can not nest html tags inside each other. Best solution is to use a iframe instead.

```
$("#includedContent").html("<iframe src='a.html'></iframe>");
```

Comment: your file path is incorrect then.. open that html file in a web page, paste the entire URL into the src then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For security reasons browsers don't allow to load files using such methods which involves XHR/AJAX.

`$("#includedContent").load("a.html");`

You need to host/deploy files on server, try using XAMPP/WAMPP or equivalent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use load() if you are trying to load a specific selector but if you are trying to load the entire page use get(), please see in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246137/ajax-jquery-load-versus-jquery-get) the differences between jQuery.get() and jQuery.load();

```
$.get('a.html', appndHtml);
function appndHtml(data){
   $("#includedContent").prepend(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#some-container').load('path-name.html'); 
 });
```

The document should be ready, or fully loaded.